# Static linking of libpq++ postgresql in C++

Tags: c++, postgresql, static, static-libraries, static-linking

I am moving an application from MySQL to Postgres. When I try to compile a simple application that connects to the database, I can link it with `libpq.lib` and have a successful compilation and execution. However, this requires me to to include about 8 `.dll` files in the directory of my program which is very aggravating. Is there a way to statically link `libpq.lib` so I do not need any `.dll` files? I am on Windows7 x64 and I am trying to target building a architecture independent application that works on x64 and x86 windows. I am using libpq version 8.4.9.1. Thanks!

Update: I have tried adding `#define PQ_STATIC` and `-static` to the linker flags. I have also compiled `libpq.a` from source but none of the above have worked.

Answer (score 4):

Libpq needs some pretty big libraries like openssl for encrypted connections, zlib for compression, iconv for character set conversions etc. You'd have to compile all of them to static library, then libpq to static library and then your program statically. I think it's too much work for too little gain.

There's a commercial tool, [PgWare Alloy 4](http://www.pgware.com/products/alloy/), which can be used to merge DLL's with EXE. I suppose it just extracts all merged files to temporary directory and then runs your program from this directory.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there are two kinds of libraries. One compiled for dynamic linking and another for static linking. In your case, you might be linking with library compiled for dynamic linking. So, what you need is library for static linking. In many cases, such file is named as `*_s.lib` denoting statically linkable library.

In Linux, `.a` files are the static libraries. Once you link with these, you won't need them during the runtime. Whereas in Windows, you always compile and link with `.lib` files. During the compilation phase, you won't find any difference. Some of those `.lib` files contain the actual code. These are the static libraries. Others contain pointer to implementation in separate `.dll`.

Comment: I just tried compiling the library from source and got libpq.a which I then linked with the application for a successful compilation. However, I am still unable to run the program without the `.dll` files. I think there is some sort of `#define` I am missing or compiler flag. Note, the `libpq.a` is larger than `libpq.lib`.

Comment: `libpq.a` will be larger than `libpq.lib` as it contains the implementation.